# I need to analyse the xml string below

Tags: java, xml

The service at this address http://www.cs12333.com:8001/Service/PersonSearchService returns the following XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body><ns2:findPersonListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.person.search/">
       <return>
       <result>true</result>
       <resultList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                       xsi:type="ns2:grxxBean">
       <aab001>cooperation</aab001>
       <aac001>34305742</aac001>
       <aac002>430423198906237024</aac002>
       <aac003>licong</aac003>
       <aac004>2</aac004>
       <aac031>2</aac031>`    
       <pwd>1</pwd>
       </resultList>
       </return>
       </ns2:findPersonListResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I'm reading the values like this:

```
dom = DocumentHelper.parseText(result);
Element root=dom.getRootElement();
```

The root's value is `"org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement@db23f1 [Element: <S:Envelope schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/attributes: []/>]"`.

How do I get the value of tag `<aac003>`?

Comment: You should use the corresponding Web Services (SOAP) client implementation, instead of parsing this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expath to get `<aac003>` value

```
/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:findPersonListResponse/*:return/*:resultList/*:aac003
```